# How can I use newline with the Find-And-Replace in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, regex, find-and-replace, newlines

I've become rather fond of the "Find-And-Replace" function in Visual Studio.  The function lets me replace phrases, words, symbols, or whatever you can type into the textbox on the screen.

How can I make it replace a character with a newline?

Comment: Make sure that you do not have Match Case or Match Whole Word set as this breaks in VS2012.

Comment: There is similar question in SO [Visual studio find and replace - Add carriage return, OR Newline](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4336417)

Answer (score 19):

According to [Helixoft: Multiline Search and Replace in Visual Studio](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/15)
you can enable Regular Expressions and then use `\n` to indicate a new line.

Comment: Also, if you're Finding and must cross a line, be careful to include \r\n to indicate that, as these don't get caught in wildcards.

Comment: This doesn't work in vs 2013

Comment: @Marwin: Please note that some documents contain `\r` too. It works for me in VS 2013...

Comment: \r\n worked, it is because of the windows line endings I guess. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Select text.
Select the little asterisk control immediately to the right of the whole word control, to enable regular expressions.
Enter \r\n into find box
Enter replacement into "Replace..."
Replace all (or replace next)